# A question about the set of probability vectors

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems, entropy

Let
\begin{equation}
P= \{(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}: x_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i=1\}
\end{equation}
Every $p\in P$ is called probability vector.

The following notation is introduced in a book, but they, $P_m$ and $p_{(m)}$, are not clear for me. Can you help me with an example to understand them?

Assume that $P_m$ denote the subset of $P$ consisting of all $m$-dimensional probability vectors i.e. satisfying $p_i=0$ for all $i>m$.

For $p\in P$, we let $p_{(m)}\in P_m$ denote the vector obtained from $p$ by taking its $m-1$ largest term and, as the $m$th term, the sum of the rest, and ordering the resulting $m$-terms decreasingly.

Comment: Two elements from $P_4$ are (0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0, 0, ...) and (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...).

Comment: I can't make sense of $p_{(m)}$. It only seems to specify two elements, the $m-1$ term in the original vector and a sum as $m^{th}$ term, but then contradicts itself by re-ordering the elements in decreasing order?